# Create GUIText at run time

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to dynamically create some GUIText at runtime in Unity3D.

```
void start()
{
    GameObject bananas = new GameObject("SomeGUIText");
    Instantiate(bananas);
    GUIText myText = bananas.AddComponent<GUIText>();
    myText.transform.position = new Vector3(0.5f,0.5f,0f);
    myText.guiText.text = "Hello";
}
```

No errors, only nothing shows up! What am I missing?

Comment: Capitalize the "s" in `start()`

Comment: Nooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo  !#SirBraneDamuj Copy that, & I'll accept that as the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capitalize "s" in `start()`. Remember to do that for things like `Update()`, `Awake()`, etc. Generally, your function names should be capitalized in C#.